# Magnific popup - onclose

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I have an application that opens a popup - and then a link inside will open up another. But when they close the 2nd popup - it closes both.

What would be the action to onclosing the 2nd popup - but reopening the first.

```
$('.popup-close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();
    console.log("reopen lost popup");

    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: '#firstPopup'
        },
        type: 'inline',
        showCloseBtn: false
    });
});
```

-- but is it because $.magnificPopup.close - hasn't finished closing? Is there a way to be selective as to which popup gets closed - like $('secondPopup').magnificPopup.close() ?

//jsfiddle with the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/bdLAN/72/

Comment: I think that you need to use script that supports multiple instances, for example, fancybox3

Comment: its an integrated lib - used all over the place in this application - if there is a solution for this one bug that will be great

Comment: -- this is the problem I am facing -- http://jsfiddle.net/68j8fyc6/40/

Comment: This is not a bug, this is just a missing feature.

Comment: @Janis - how to resolve it then - with this library

Comment: It is like saying - "I bought a car, but it is not flying. How to fix this bug?"

Comment: I've got a solution - http://jsfiddle.net/68j8fyc6/66/

Comment: @Janis - yes that's all well and good - but when you are working on a large enterprise level website with proper code releases and a person in the past chose a particular lib -- its not such a simple technical solution to throw out and replace the code - as its not part of the same kaban story now. I got other cards to work on here - not just trying to hotfix a one-time usage of a double popup